# Find a linear operator such that $\|T\| > \sup_{\|f\| \leq 1} \left|\langle Tf, f \rangle\right|$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, self-learning

> Find a linear operator $T: \mathbb C^2 \to \mathbb C^2$ such that $$\|T\| > \sup_{\|f\| \leq 1} \left|\langle Tf, f \rangle\right|,$$ where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the standard inner product.

I know that $$\|T\| := \sup_{f \neq 0} \frac{\|Tf\|}{\|f\|} = \sup_{\|f\|=1} \|Tf\| = \sup_{\|f\|\leq 1} \|Tf\|.$$ This does not seem to be helpful. Any help, please? Thank you!

Comment: $\langle\cdot\rangle$ is the standard scalar product or *another* scalar product?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla It is standard inner product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: what happens if $T$ is a rotation?

Comment: Then $\|T\| = 1$, but I do NOT see why this will give strict $>$ unless one assumes that rotation of a non-zero angle. Right?

Comment: Right. The easier case is 90 degrees.